# Make div fixed to bottom above another div

Tags: html, css

I've been developing a mobile layout with a horizontal scroll.

But now I have a problem:

There is a NAV element that sticks to the bottom of the page, no problem there, but I want to achieve an effect of a "corkboard" with the accompanying "frames" on the top and on the bottom. Once again, the top one is no problem at all, but I'm having a lot of trouble trying to get the bottom one to stay at the bottom, and above the NAV bar.

It's something like this:
[image]

Basically, the red square is the current view/screen, the navbar stays fixed to the bottom and if I scroll to another section it stays at the bottom of the screen as intended, as does the top blue bar (the top frame).

How can I make the bottom blue bar to stay in the position intended/exemplified?

The HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Ptfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faster+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#splash">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#next">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#circuit">Circuit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <section id="splash">
                <header>About Me</header>
                <div>
                    Lorem ipsum just testing things
                </div>
                </section>
            <section id="next">
                <div id="frame-top">
                    <header>Portfolio</header>

                    <div id="content">&nbsp</div>
                </div>
                <div id="frame-bottom">&nbsp</div>
            </section>
            <section id="circuit">
                <header>Contact</header>
                <div class="main">
                </div>
            </section>
        </div> <!-- wrapper -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS:

```
        /* --Meyerweb */
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/* --Meyerweb */

html, body { 
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

#wrapper { 
    display: table; 
    width: 350%; 
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    position: relative;
}

#wrapper > section { 
    display: table-cell; 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 25%;
}

header {
    min-height: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
}


section#splash {
    background: url("../img/bg_grey.png") repeat;
}

section#splash > header {
    font-family: 'Faster One', cursive;
}

section#next {
    background: url("../img/cork.jpg") repeat;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-bottom: 3.938em;
}

#frame-top {
    background: url("../img/frame.png") repeat-x;
    background-position: top;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

#frame-bottom {
    background: url("../img/frame.png") repeat-x;
    height: 16px;
    background-position: top;
    z-index: 4;
}

#content {
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}

section#circuit {
    background: url("../img/circuit-tile-02.png") repeat;
}

.st-scroll {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;

    /* Let's enforce some hardware acceleration */
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

nav {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.3, #303030),
        color-stop(0.5, #212121),
        color-stop(0.7, #575657)
    );
    height: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}

nav ul {
    width:  50%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

nav ul li{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I've tryed everything from margins, paddings, heigth and min-height but can't manage to achieve the intended effect.
Can anyope point me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: A screenshot of the page at the moment on:
Chrome -
[image]

Safari - 
[image]

Comment: EDITED the content to reflect recent changes which still don't solve the problem, but mitigate it...

Comment: Looking closer at this, I realized that the <nav> element is hiding a horizontal scrollbar on the body element. Didn't have time to look at it yesterday, but I'll see if I can't tease something out today.

Comment: Hi joequincy, In the meantime, I managed to solve that and will post the code soon :). Once again, thank you

Comment: I'm interested to see the differences between your solution and mine. Your use of `display: table`/`table-cell;` was causing bizarre layout issues on my end, so I switched to `block`/`inline-block`, and reduced the CSS footprint overall... but had to do some hack-ey things to overcome a couple webkit layout quirks with inline-block. The resulting layout is identical in both Windows Chrome and Android "Browser", Firefox, Chrome, Dolphin, and Skyfire (Opera has a bug that affects `position: fixed` when combined with `z-index`)

Comment: I'm going to answer my own question bellow, with the code posted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help from @joequincy and much hacking and tampering with the code I've reached the perfect solution:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Ptfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chango' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Solid' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#splash">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#next">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#circuit">Circuit</a></li>
            <li>Placeholder</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="cell">
            <section id="splash">
                <header>Celso Santos</header>
                <div class="container">
                    <div>
                        Lorem ipsum just testing things
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">  
            <section id="next">
                <header>Portfolio</header>
                <div id="frame-top"></div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div id="content">&nbsp</div>
                    </div>
                <div id="frame-bottom"></div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <section id="circuit">
                <header>Contact</header>
                <div class="container"></div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- wrapper -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS:

```
/* --Meyerweb */
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/* --Meyerweb */

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 300%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: -3em;
}

#wrapper > .cell { display: table-cell; height: 100%; width: 25%; }

#wrapper > .cell > section { position: relative; height: 100%; }

.container { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 4em; right: 15px; bottom: 4em; left: 15px; 
  overflow-y: auto; border: 1px solid #000000; }

#wrapper > section {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
}

header {
    min-height: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}


section#splash {
    background: url("../img/bg_grey.png") repeat;
}

section#splash > header {
    font-family: 'Chango', cursive;
}

section#next {
    background: url("../img/cork.jpg") repeat;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

section#next > header {
    top: 20px;
    font-family: 'Londrina Solid', cursive;
    color: rgba(124, 52, 24, 0.92);
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.83);
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

section#next > div#frame-top {
    background: url("../img/frame.png") repeat-x;
    background-position: top;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 16px;
}

#frame-top > header {
    font-family: 'Londrina Solid', cursive;
    color: rgba(124, 52, 24, 0.92);
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.83);
}

#next > .container {
    bottom: 5em;
}

#frame-bottom {
    background: url("../img/frame.png") repeat-x;
    height: 16px;
    background-position: top;
    z-index: 4;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3em;
    width: 100%;
}

#content {
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    min-height: 100%;
}

section#circuit {
    background: url("../img/circuit-tile-02.png") repeat;
}

#circuit > header {
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #666;
}

.st-scroll {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;

    /* Let's enforce some hardware acceleration */
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

nav {
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #333333 10%, #525252 50%, #525252 80%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #333333 10%, #525252 50%, #525252 80%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #333333 10%, #525252 50%, #525252 80%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #333333 10%, #525252 50%, #525252 80%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #333333 10%, #525252 50%, #525252 80%);
    box-shadow: 0px -3px 3px #333333;
}

nav ul {
    width:  80%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

nav ul li{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I kept the table-cell, aligned everything perfectly (even with those awkward "spaces") and then to keep everything tidy the big secret was to use overflow:hidden in the body.
Now, this does have other problems such as that you cannot scroll vertically nor horizontally now, but given that that wasn't a problem (navigation is supposed to be achieved using the navbar to simulate different views) it now works correctly, without any JS.

Comment: Ah. Yeah, I assumed horizontal scrolling would be necessary, so my solution (unposted) reflects that. On the plus side, as a result of spending that time, I uncovered a bug in Opera Mobile... so I was able to do something productive with it. :P

Comment: Now you got me interested in the code you wrote :P Could you share it? :)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading correctly, the problem is that the background is hanging out at the top of the element instead of the bottom?

Add `background-position: bottom;` to that element's style.

---

Edit to add my solution css:

- HTML is unchanged from the original post
- "Meyerweb" CSS left unchanged
- Changed CSS:

```css
html, body { 
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {
    overflow-x: auto;
    /* allows that horizontal scrolling */
}

#wrapper {  
    width: 350%; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    /* ^-- these three lines replace height:100%
     * and correct some layout quirks */
}
#wrapper > section { 
    display: inline-block; 
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
}

#wrapper > section:first-child  {
    margin-left: 0px;
    /* combined with -4px margin above, eliminates gaps between sections */
}

#wrapper > section, section > header, section > div {
    width: 25%;
    /* not sure why 25%, since you seem to only
     * have three sections... but either way,
     * the same value is needed in multiple locations
     * so it's pulled out on its own here for
     * ease of maintenance  */
}

section > header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 3em;
}
section > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 3em;
    padding-bottom: 3em; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

section#splash { /*unchanged*/
    background: url("../img/bg_grey.png") repeat;
}
section#next { /*unchanged*/
    background: url("../img/cork.jpg") repeat;
    z-index: 1;
}
section#next > header#frame-top { /*unchanged*/
    background: url("../img/frame.png") repeat-x;
    background-position: top;
    z-index: 3;
}
section#next > div#frame-bottom {
    background: url("../img/frame.png") repeat-x;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-origin: content-box;
    z-index: 3;
}
section#circuit { /*unchanged*/
    background: url("../img/circuit-tile-02.png") repeat;
}

.st-scroll { /*unchanged*/
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;

    /* Let's enforce some hardware acceleration */
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

nav {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.3, #303030),
        color-stop(0.5, #212121),
        color-stop(0.7, #575657)
    );
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #303030 30%, #212121 50%, #575657 70%);
    /* ^-- for non-webkit */
    height: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
}

nav ul { /*unchanged*/
    width:  50%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

nav ul li{ /*unchanged*/
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: That appears to be part of the solution, but I still get a scroll bar, which I don't want.. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see anything about a scroll bar in the question or the screenshot. Which element is it attached to, and which direction does it scroll?

Comment: Sorry I edited the post to correct the imagem. It's a vertical scroll which I believe comes because of the #next section

Comment: Yes, it is because of `section#next` because it has a `height:100%` and `section#splash` has a `height:5em`, pushing it down within the wrapper. I'd recommend setting `section#next` to have `-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; margin-top: -5em; padding-top: 5em;` and see where that takes you (add other prefixed box-sizing properties after you're sure it's working... webkit doesn't own mobile _completely_).

Comment: It's not that either... Would it be too much trouble if I ziped and posted the html and css file for you to take a look at? I honestly can't figure it out and it's driving me crazy

Comment: Sure. Make sure you include the background images so that I can be sure of spacing and all that.

Comment: Just a quick thought, wouldn't it be better if I got the viewport size and placed the image according to that, being it a "fixed" value manipulated through javascript?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22649/discussion-between-joequincy-and-zed-blade)

Answer (score 0):

Use "bottom:0px" instead of margin. I haven't looked too deep into this, but I have a project of my own with divs aligned to the bottom, and fixed.